# BASH script - print sorted contents from all files in directory with no rep's

Tags: bash, sorting, printing

In the current directory there are files with names of the form "gradesXXX" (where XXX is a course number) which look like this:

```
ID           GRADE         (this line is not contained in the files)
123456789    56
213495873    84
098342362    77
.            .
.            .
.            .
```

I want to write a BASH script that prints all the IDs that have a grade above a certain number, which is given as the first parameter to said script.

The requirements are that an ID must be printed once at most, and that no intermediate files are used.
I was guided to use two scripts - the first with length of one line, and the second with length of up to six lines (not including the "#!" line).

I'm quite lost with this one so any suggestions will be appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I was looking for was

```
// internal script
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    line_split=( $line )
    if (( ${line_split[1]} > $1 )); then
        echo ${line_split[0]}
    fi
done

// external script
#!/bin/bash
cat grades* | sort -r -n -k 1 | internalScript $1 | cut -f1 -d" " | uniq
```

Comment: Nice you managed this. To avoid two scripts encapsulate them in functions in just one file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a simple solution.

```
cat grades[0-9][0-9][0-9] | sort -nurk 2 | while read ID GRADE ; do if [ $GRADE -lt 60 ] ; then break ; fi ; echo $ID ; done | sort -u
```

I'm not sure why two scripts should be necessary. All in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=$1
cat grades[0-9][0-9][0-9] | sort -nurk 2 | while read ID GRADE ; do if [ $GRADE -lt $threshold ] ; then break ; fi ; echo $ID ; done | sort -u
```

We first cat all the grade files, the sort them by grade in reverse order. The while loop breaks if grade is below threshold, so that only lines with higher grades get their ID printed. `sort -u` makes sure that every ID is sent only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ($2 > 70) print $1 }' grades777
```

It prints the first column of every line which seconds column is greater than 70. If you need to change the threshold:

```
N=71
awk '{ if ($2 > '$N') print $1 }' grades777
```

That `'` are required to [pass shell variables in AWK](http://chihungchan.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/four-ways-to-pass-shell-variables-in.html). To work with all `grade???` files in the current directory and remove duplicated lines:

```
awk '{ if ($2 > '$N') print $1 }' grades??? | sort -u
```

A simple one-line solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
cat grades[0-9][0-9][0-9] | awk -v MAX=70 '{ if ($2 > MAX) foo[$1]=1 }END{for (id in foo) print id }'
```

Append `| sort -n` after that if you want the IDs in sorted order.

Comment: @sputnick I see the point, as you can also do `awk ... files`; however, note that particular award is generally about using `cat` with a *single* file (but could probably be generalized in this sense), and in this particular case it serves as a placeholder to aid in adapting the solution to other uses (e.g. if there is other pre-processing such such as stripping headers before the `awk` step).

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash` :

```
N=60
for file in /path/*; do
    while read id grade; do ((grade > N)) && echo "$id"; done < "$file"
done
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
213495873
098342362
```